# UWP: How to access ApplicationData

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, winapi, uwp, local-storage

I am trying to create a Settings Value for my UWP-JS App on Startup.
I am following this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

Here is what I've currently got:

```
(function () {
    "use strict"

    //Initialization
    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings;
    // Save value
    localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "example";
    // Retrieve value
    $('p').text(localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"]);
})();
```

When I start the Application it enters 'Break Mode' with the following exception in line 7 of the given code:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'exampleSetting' of undefined or null reference

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Properties are camelCase, so `Values` should be `values`. This follows common JS convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `current` property, which is also mentioned in the example you refered to. So your call should be:

```
(function () {
    "use strict"

    //Initialization
    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings;
    // Save value
    localSettings.values["exampleSetting"] = "example";
    // Retrieve value
    $('p').text(localSettings.values["exampleSetting"]);
})();
```

**Edit:**
The properties and method names after `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData` need to be start with lowercase.

Comment: Yes, I already tried it with that and that gave me the following error: `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'LocalSettings' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: @jonhue See my edit. It was just a lower case problem. But still you need to call 'current'

Comment: Infact I now get the following error: `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'exampleSetting' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Ah I forgot to also change `Values` to `values`. How do I know whether these methods have to start lowercase or uppercase?

Comment: @jonhue Nice that i could help you. To the lower case thing: I typically write my WinJS-Application with typescript, there i have a declaration file, which helps by these things. But I think you can follow the rule, that everything after the class name [here ApplicationData] is written in lowercase

Comment: By the way, do you know a way of iterating through all values?

Comment: All values of the settings? BTW: comments are not for further question, which are not related to the original question. If you cant find a solution to your new problem, ask a new one in a new post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136468/discussion-between-thetanic-and-jonhue).